# Image not loading properly in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm using JS to create an entire page.
So in a table where I put an image, I have a snippet as follows:

```
col = document.createElement("td");

var img = document.createElement("IMG");
img.setAttribute("src", plane.innerHTML);
img.setAttribute("width", "304");
img.setAttribute("height", "228");
img.setAttribute("alt", plane.innerHTML);
col.appendChild(img);
row.appendChild(col);
```

**Extra info if you need**:

Later I add this row to a table:

```
ntable.appendChild(row);
```

and much later I open a new window with this table:

```
w =window.open("","","width=700,height=700");
w.document.write("<body></body>");  
w.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(ntable);
w.document.close();
```

**Issue:**

When the window pops up for the first time, all I see is the image alternate texts. I need to right click on them and reload to see the images (meaning the images are there in the column but don't show up on opening the window.)

*Browser details*: It works fine on Chrome, but this issue is persistent in Firefox.

[image]

Comment: What does the actual html output look like in firefox?  A [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: @yezzz The left screenshot is in firefox, the right one is in chrome.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that, but a complete code sample and resulting html markup would give a clue if there's any flaw in your code (that chrome can deal with, but FF can't). Is FF giving any error in your console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem.

Instead of making variables and using DOM functions, I just made an HTML text by setting a long string with the entire HTML document and finally writing the HTML document using the `document.write` method. That seemed to solve the problem of the images not loading.

Answer (score 1):

I think using insertCell might help

```
HTMLTableRowElement.insertCell()
```

Comment: No that does not change anything.